# @rollup/plugin-typescript Can't find JSON file

Tags: json, typescript, svelte

I have setup a Svelte project and want to use JSON files to use the Svelte i18n package.
Unfortunately I have trouble importing a JSON file.
The needed package for it is installed, but I have no idea why the Typescript aspect of it wouldn't accept it.

I have a minimal [repro here](https://github.com/BirgitPohl/Svelte-i18n-gnag).

```
import App from './App.svelte';

// src/index.js
import pkg from './package.json';
console.log(`running version ${pkg.version}`);

const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
    props: {
        name: "hello"
    }
});

export default app;
```

Importing a JSON file results in the following error message:

```sh
(!) Plugin typescript: @rollup/plugin-typescript TS2732: Cannot find module './locale.de.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension
```

//rollup.config.js

```js
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

function serve() {
    let server;
    
    function toExit() {
        if (server) server.kill(0);
    }

    return {
        writeBundle() {
            if (server) return;
            server = require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
                stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                shell: true
            });

            process.on('SIGTERM', toExit);
            process.on('exit', toExit);
        }
    };
}

export default {
    input: 'src/main.ts',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        json({
            compact: true
        }),
        svelte({
            dev: !production,
            css: css => {
                css.write('bundle.css');
            },
            preprocess: sveltePreprocess(),
        }),

        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: ['svelte']
        }),
        commonjs(),
        typescript({
            sourceMap: !production,
            inlineSources: !production
        }),

        !production && serve(),
        !production && livereload('public'),
        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};
```

//tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "module": "esnext",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/*", "__sapper__/*", "public/*"]
}
```

Comment: I've had a look at your repo `register('en', () => import('../../public/lang/en.json'));
register('de', () => import('./locale.de.json'));` --> where is `'./locale.de.json'`?

Comment: It's in the public folder assuming something could happening there. It's basically a trial and error from my side. I rather expect the first version to function. Thanks for having a look.

Comment: So does the above en.json import work since the error shows for the de.json file? If nothing works, move those json files into your `src` folder if it's not important for them to be in `public`. The problem is probably in the config's exclude or include, or maybe some related setting, I'm not sure at the top of my head what's the config for the public folder

Comment: I have setup everything I found in the documentations of rollup about typescript and json. Or I must have overseen something. I have two different paths with the files in the respected place, but it errors in both of them as well as in the package.json. According to the `@rollup/plugin-json` documentation is should be possible to import a package.json.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: This issue hapens when I upgrade my project from Node 18 to 20.

Comment: Yeah, I accepted an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problems. Adding `resolveJsonModule: true` in each typescript call in the `rollup.config.js` solves the issues.

That leads me to the point that the rollup plugin does not merge the tsconfig with overrides in the expected way.

rollup.config.js

```
typescript({
    sourceMap: dev,
    inlineSources: dev,
    resolveJsonModule: true
  })
```

tsconfig.js

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["DOM", "ES2017", "WebWorker"]
  },
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "include": ["src/**/*", "src/node_modules/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/*", "__sapper__/*", "", "static/*"],
  "types": ["svelte", "@sapper"]
}
```

Btw. i'am also testeing around with i18n ;).